# DataSnap XE2 Server - Uses GZIP compression?

Tags: delphi, compression, gzip, delphi-xe2, datasnap

Does anybody know if a DataSnap server (using HTTP/HTTPS) built with Delphi XE2 uses GZIP compression for it's responses by default?  Is there any way of enabling/disabling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataSnap compression is done using the TDSHTTPService.Filters: (TTransportFilterCollection)
You can add several filters, for compression, criptografy, etc.

The built-in compression filter uses ZLib, and the IDE wizard have a option to add it automatically.

Check the TDSHTTPService.Filters property and if the ZLibCompression filter is there, you can remove to disable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the ZLibCompression filter (via Filter property) to wizard created DSXXXServerTransport1 component. Where XXX represents the protocol.

Comment: How does one invoke the wizard?

Comment: @ChrisGerken The wizard is invoked for new projects in menu: File > New > Other > Delphi Projects > DataSnap Server: and then select the type of project, usually "DataSnap Server"